# The ionic 3 fab button does not work properly on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, floating-action-button

I was making a simple drop-down list with the fab component, with ionic 3

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-fab top right #fab>
    <button ion-fab type="button">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-fab-list side="down" >
      <button type="button" ion-fab color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="globe"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button type="button" ion-fab color="primary" (click)="openDocumentLibraries(fab)">
        <ion-icon name="folder"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button type="button" ion-fab color="primary" (click)="openSearchPage(fab)">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

When clicked it doesn't show the list on iOS. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: hooking an event on the click I noticed it calls the event twice even if I make a single tap